# Can we Embed Linkedin Page inside SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, modern-experience, embedded

Inside our SharePoint online modern home page >> we have embedded our Twitter page and Facebook page. but we did not find any option to embed our LinkedIn page.. can anyone advice if this is achievable ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the embed web part to embed LinkedIn content in SharePoint Online:

[Add content to your page using the Embed web part](https://support.microsoft.com/office/add-content-to-your-page-using-the-embed-web-part-721f3b2f-437f-45ef-ac4e-df29dba74de8)

[Embed Content from the LinkedIn Feed](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/a529065/embed-content-from-the-linkedin-feed?lang=en)

Comment: i can embed certain posts,, but not the whole feed

Comment: This isn't a problem with SharePoint, but rather limitations that LinkedIn have imposed. Please mark this as the answer, if it answers your SharePoint related problem.